# Where is Magento session serialized?

Tags: php, magento, session, serialization

I am getting this fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 
'Serialization of 'Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element' is not allowed' 
in [no active file]:0 Stack trace: #0 {main}   
thrown in [no active file] on line 0
```

I understand it is trying to serialize `Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element` and failing, yet I have never used `getNode()`, it's always `getStoreConfig()` for me.

I am happy to debug this, if I could just find **WHERE** it is being generated. Where is the Magento session being serialized?

Note: trying to echo the serialization in footer (like one thread suggested) does not work in this case. The session is not being set (cause of this error) and so there is no error when it gets to the footer...

Comment: Searching for the usage of function [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/session_write_close) can lead you a way but it's usage is rather widespread so there is no quick, distinct answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the error that caused this. However was interested in finding out where is the place to debug this, but as there is no proper answer to this, no reason to wait longer.

Anyways, the problem is adding a model object to session, which obviously then is a no-no. At one point or another it must contain that class of an element.

Comment: I'm also struggling with this error. Any pointers on finding the files you were adding the model object to a session?

Comment: For me it was pretty obvious as I was developing a module that added things to the session. I would recommend checking any third party modules you have installed since Magento core doesn't do this for the very same reason any other developer shouldn't - the error in the original post. :) Otherwise there are options as well - before session save try to go over the objects and see if you spot anything. Once you see an object - search for setData(X... and setX where X is the key it is saved with. That would be my first suggestion.